# speaking url in TYPO3 9.5 shows always homepage

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

my problem:

- i defined a site with one language (german).
- i installed the htaccess from TYPO3 without changings.
- normal redirects and mod_rewrites work
- all pages are shown correctly when i call them via index.php?id=

But when i call them with their slugs i get in every case the homepage.

The same installation works pretty well on my local development but not on the staging server.

my config.yaml:

```
rootPageId: 39
base: 'https://test.mydomain.de'
baseVariants: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: German
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: German
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: i deactivated all extensions but nothing changed. No error message. How could i debug this problem?

Comment: There is a bug, look here : [https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87885#change-397824](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87885#change-397824) Florian

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the same problem - when adding https as base the routing ends on the homepage. Thanks! I will check wether there is a problem with the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the reason and a fix.

- Yes, it was the same problem as in https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87885#change-397824 - Thanks Florian.
- it is not a bug but a wrong configuration

We added this to the configuration of the frontend proxy:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

and in the installtool we added:

```
[SYS][reverseProxyIP] = 1.2.3.4, ... (all IPs of the proxy)
```

After both configuration changes it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in the environment with Apache2 reverse proxy. Setting http instead of https in the Site config in Entry point and setting "/" in language Entry point solved the problem for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and this "solved" it for me. I did not set up a reverse proxy and the configuration was pretty simple. I just originally configured the site with http and then later used https.